# Color line below title in PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I have implemented a FragmentPagerAdapter of 4-pages and a PagerTitleStrip with the titles of each of them. I wanted to know if there are any attributes to put a color line below title to highlight the one selected at the time.

I've looked PagerTitleStrip attributes but I have not found anything for this purpose.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to achieve a solution to your problem using one of the following libraries:

- [Pager Sliding TabStrip](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/)
- [Android ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Answer (score 1):

Put a new line at the top of all 4 layout and make it invisible. When certain page come. OnPageSelected make this line visible.